# Python Merge Two DataFrames Only Retrieve Specific Columns in the Result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

[image: Two DataFrames]

Hi - I want to merge two python DataFrames, but don't want to bring over ALL of the columns from both dataframes to my new dataframe.  In the picture below, if I join df1 and df2 on 'acct' and want to bring back all the columns from df1 and ONLY 'entity' from df2, how would I write that?  I don't want to have to drop any columns so doing a normal merge isn't what I'm looking for.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform the merge operation, you can modify a dataframe object that is in your function, which will mean the underlying objects df1 and df2 remain unchanged. An example would look like this:

```
df_result = df1.merge(df2[ ['acct','entity'] ], on ='acct')
```

This will let you do your partial merge without modifying either original dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  One additional question, what if the joining columns are differently named in the above example.  Say, if df1 had a column 'acct' and df2 had 'account', but I still only wanted to bring back certain columns like in my original post.  Thanks again!

Comment: If column names that you want to join on are different, you can do this: `df_result = df1.merge(df2[['account','entity']], left_on ='acct', right_on='account')`.